# In Orchard 1.3.10 and Advanced Menu 1.3 using classes "Current" and "Selected"

Tags: menu, orchardcms

I'm using Orchard 1.3.10 and Advanced Menu 1.3 i have an issue with the classes assigned (current and selected).

I have a menu item "Teste1" and another menu item "Teste1 Sample".

When i selected the "Teste1 Sample", is inserted the class "current" to this, and insert "current selected" to "Teste1" item.

They are at the same level.

```
<ul id="menu-20" class="menu menu-main sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow">
    <li><a class="title" href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="current selected"><a class="title" href="/Orchard1.3.10/teste1">teste1</a></li>
    <li><a class="title" href="/Orchard1.3.10/teste2">teste2</a></li>
    <li><a class="title" href="/Orchard1.3.10/teste3">teste3</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a class="title" href="/Orchard1.3.10/teste1-sample">teste1 sample</a></li>
    <li><a class="title" href="/Orchard1.3.10/teste12">Teste12</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or if i select the "Teste12" is the same issue.
I don't know why this is happening.
Is this a Bug?

Comment: It's obviously a bug. I'm currently investigating it and will push a fix.